# How to convert kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange to kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA sample buffer?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, webrtc

I am worked with webrtc and I capture images using below video setting.

[image]

But I need to stay with this video setting and when capture output method call that time I want to convert sample buffer `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` to `kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA`.

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The vImage library in Apple's Accelerate framework will do this for you. Take a look at the [Converting Chroma-Subsampled Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/conversion/converting_chroma-subsampled_images) article which, I think, describes exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Also, I believe VideoToolbox in CoreMedia.